# Integration (by parts?) with fractional powers

Tags: integration

Trying to solve a simple (?) integration problem that Mathematica doesn't like:

$$\int x^{3/2} e^x\mathrm d x$$

I thought the solution would be integration by parts with some clever change of variables, but I can't seem to find it.  Can I get a hint?

Comment: I would not expect this to have a pleasant form.  You could define $z=\sqrt x$ but you'll then bump up against $\int e^{x^2}dx$

Comment: mathematica returns $\frac{3}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)+e^x \left(x^{3/2}-\frac{3 \sqrt{x}}{2}\right)$. What's the issue?

Comment: $erfi(\sqrt x)$ seemed wrong, I guess.  Maybe I need to discard the imaginary part.

Comment: what imaginary part? $\mathrm{erfi}(x)$ is real-valued for real $x$